# interrupt output if input is detected

Tags: loops, input, tcl

I want to send informational to the CLI every second. To prevent the script to run indefinitely, i would like the output loop to stop, if user input is detected. I have something like this:

```
namespace eval vars {
    # counter as failsave
    set counter 1
}
set stop 0

proc print_message {} {
    if {$::vars::counter == 50} {
        break
    }
    puts "Printing message..."
    incr ::vars::counter
    after 1000 print_message
}

# Start the message printing loop
print_message

# Check for user input
while {!$stop} {
  set input [gets stdin]
  if {$input == "x"} {
    set stop 1
  }
}
puts "Stopped printing messages"
```

But this does not work. As soon as i get any gets stdin, the script stopps and does not give any output anymore. Right now, i have the script running with a count workaround, but im not happy with the result.

```
roPWB12#get lte history 50
  1  16.02.2023 14:24:22   RSSI: -63 dB        RSRP: -92 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 20.4 dB       
 25  16.02.2023 14:24:46   RSSI: -63 dB        RSRP: -92 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 15.8 dB (-4.6)
Press enter for another 50 measurements or enter new amount of repeats... 
 51  16.02.2023 14:34:23   RSSI: -63 dB        RSRP: -92 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 21.2 dB (+5.4)
 58  16.02.2023 14:34:30   RSSI: -63 dB        RSRP: -92 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 20.2 dB (-1.0)
Press enter for another 50 measurements or enter new amount of repeats... 100
101  16.02.2023 14:38:23   RSSI: -63 dB        RSRP: -92 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 14.6 dB (-5.6)
140  16.02.2023 14:39:01   RSSI: -63 dB        RSRP: -92 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 14.8 dB (+0.2)
184  16.02.2023 14:39:46   RSSI: -63 dB        RSRP: -92 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 13.8 dB (-1.0)
Press enter for another 100 measurements or enter new amount of repeats... 
201  20.02.2023 11:18:15   RSSI: -64 dB (-1)   RSRP: -97 dB (-5)   RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 12.6 dB (-1.2)
245  20.02.2023 11:18:58   RSSI: -64 dB        RSRP: -97 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 21.2 dB (+8.6)
289  20.02.2023 11:19:43   RSSI: -64 dB        RSRP: -97 dB        RSRQ: -7 dB        SNR: 17.8 dB (-3.4)
Press enter for another 100 measurements or enter new amount of repeats... 7
```

Forgot to mention: I am working with TCL 8.3 on cisco devices...

Answer (score 1):

Detecting whether there is any user input to read requires using non-blocking input techniques (otherwise the code will stop and wait indefinitely). On a normal Unix platform, they work just fine for a terminal such as you'd be using when interactively logging in remotely. (I can't tell whether Cisco devices are normal enough in this respect.) Though 8.3 is ancient now, the code below is likely to be fine: it depends on how Unix file descriptors work, and that's not changed meaningfully in a very long time.

```
# Set up; this is the critical bit
fconfigure stdin -blocking false

puts "Press Enter to halt the loop"
while true {
    after 100;     # I don't want a demonstration loop to run too free
    puts "generating some output now [incr counter]"

    # Check for a newline
    if {[gets stdin line] >= 0 || ![fblocked stdin]} {
        puts "time to stop"
        break
    }
}
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or closing your connection to the terminal will stop the loop.

Pressing any key (instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>) would *additionally* require configuring the terminal into raw mode. That requires calling `stty` or using Tcl 8.7 (which has it as a built-in feature). Easier to not require that in your situation.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your loop is correct; something about the counter handling looks suspicious to me.

Comment: The script does not crash which means all the commands are understood by TCL8.3 but sadly, there is still the same issue that there is only one output row.  After that, the script waits for an input.

Comment: Then it definitely isn't in non-blocking mode. You did include the `fconfigure` call? If you did, then you can't get what you asked for; using non-blocking I/O is the only way (given that I'm pretty sure you can't use threads on a Cisco system).

Comment: Yes, i made sure to insert the fconfigure part. Strangely, it did not bark at me, so it understands the command -blocking false. Yeah, im stuck with this over 10 year old version. Cisco never bothers to update this. they just announce more cloud stuff each year. Thank you for helping though, hope this solution will help someone else in the future.

Comment: The problem is that while Tcl can easily set the flags on the file descriptors, if the OS ignores them then there isn't much else we can do.